# Type to match typeof enum, not just a single value

Tags: typescript, enums

```
enum X {
  A = 'x',
  B = 'y'
}

type A<T> = {
  prop1: T
  prop2: ?
}

let r:A<X> = {
  prop1: X.A,
  prop2: X
}
```

Which type must A.prop2 have to make X and only X assignable to it?

(and by only X, I mean without using any and other "tricks")

Comment: You can't derive the type of the value named `X` from the type named `X`, either in general or for enums in particular. The closest you can get for an enum is `Record<string, T>` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NaL19w) but that will allow any object whose property values are `T`.  So what you're asking for is impossible; you could switch it to start with `typeof X` instead, like [this](//tsplay.dev/WzBO4W), because `typeof X` knows about the `X` type for enums.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (or find a dupe target); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I think this indeed fully addresses the question - and also solves my problem well enough! Now I just need to understand it too :) Your explanation goes a long way, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as asked.  When you declare an [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) like

```
enum X {
  A = 'x',
  B = 'y'
}
```

you are declaring a *value* named `X` (the enum object, with keys `A` and `B`) and a *type* named `X` (the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of types of the enum values, similar to `"x" | "y"`). Types and values reside in different namespaces, so there's no "connection" between them in the language.

[Generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types like

```
type A<T> = {
  prop1: T
  prop2: ⋯
}
```

take *type* arguments, not *value* arguments.  So when you write

```
type B = A<X>;
```

you are passing the *type* named `X`, similar to `"x" | "y"` into `A`.  It does not contain the information needed to require that `prop2` should be the type of the value named `X`.  After all, the type `"x" | "y"` doesn't know anything about the keys `"A"` and `"B"`.

---

If you want to keep it so that you pass in `X`, then the closest you can get is to say that `prop2` should be some object type with properties of type `X`, but with any keys.  That gives you this:

```
type A<T> = {
  prop1: T
  prop2: Record<string, T>
}

let r: A<X> = {
  prop1: X.A,
  prop2: X // okay
}

r.prop2 = { whoopsieDaisy: X.A } // also okay
```

Obviously that doesn't require the correct keys.

---

If you refactor so that you pass in `typeof X` instead of `X`, then you can get closer:

```
type A<T extends object> = {
  prop1: T[keyof T]
  prop2: T
}
```

Now `prop1` is of type `T[keyof T]`, meaning it's the union of property types of `T`.  If `T` is `typeof X` then `T[keyof T]` will be `X` (NOTE WELL: this is specifically for enums like `X` and *not* for types and values with the same name in general. Again, types and values live in different namespaces and there's no relationship between them you can rely on.  You could write `const Y = 0;` and `type Y = 1;`, and then if `T` is `typeof Y`, then `T[keyof T]` will absolutely not be `Y`).  This forces you to now supply the right keys:

```
let r: A<typeof X> = {
  prop1: X.A,
  prop2: X
}

r.prop2 = { whoopsieDaisy: X.A } // error
```

but it's still not exactly what you want; there's no way to require a particular *value* be passed.  You can only require that the value passed is of the expected type or a subtype of that type.  The following value, for example:

```
const myX = { A: X.A, B: X.B, C: 123 } as const;
```

has a type which is assignable to `typeof X`.  So nothing prevents this:

```
r.prop2 = myX; // okay
```

If it's important for you to prevent that, you'd need to start getting even more intense about your efforts, and it would still be something a determined user could work around.  I'm not going to digress further here; the point is that trying to require a particular value is antithetical to the TypeScript type system and so it is almost certainly more trouble than it's worth.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPkkhMAK5hIAaeRxSAgkgLxIDkAHmwDR3EBCLdgE82dAL6FioSLATIAwhgD2UaABda9JOuExkDADwAVAHxCC24jABOymAEYAXEmN96t+wCYXAJQjwyjYAJoZQ6jYAlsAA5tyupu6S7hgQmjYuRlTmrJZWno4uVAB0DLxWSAU+1ElS9DbFVRZIAO4AFsr2UJEQACIgkVDCRaVIycTjSDLQcIhI-gBmCOpBtO66+owmJBzqpMFQSMoARgBWAeo5Wvl2ha4A2gDWEMLKC64Auu7Wt9Vu2pNiKl0plDBsIG9qFc8toCs5qKVyjdvEVau4Gk1cq0Ol0ev1BsMEUxxEgAPSkkg2Ow2OrEQLAcJIMDCGhYhgjMpIfgjfjxBQuBxeADMYyQIEO9PCAG50Y1fkJmVQpWSKcpHiBhHVkuIgA)

Comment: This is such a great answer! I learned a lot. Thanks!